# Cube for Fibonacci

Tags: python, list, integer

Having issue in the follwing code, it looks like I am facing issue with either list or int operations, so where and how should I do the changes to correct this code:

```
cube = lambda x:x**3
def fibonacci(n):
    fb=[0,1]
    for i in range(2,n-1):
        fb.append([fibonacci(i-1)+fibonacci(i-2)])
    return fb
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print(list(map(cube, fibonacci(n))))




Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-761cca8f2b48> in <module>
      7 if __name__ == '__main__':
      8     n = int(input())
----> 9     print(list(map(cube, fibonacci(n))))

<ipython-input-9-761cca8f2b48> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 cube = lambda x:x**3
      2 def fibonacci(n):
      3     fb=[0,1]
      4     for i in range(2,n-1):
      5         fb.append([fibonacci(i-1)+fibonacci(i-2)])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: When you have problems like this, you should look at the intermediate steps and make sure they are what you think they are. For example, does this print what you think it should: `print(fibonacci(5))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be certain what you want `fibonacci()` to return. It looks like you want it to return a list since you are passing the result to `map()`. If so, the recursive calls will also return a list, to this line doesn't really make sense:

```
fb.append([fibonacci(i-1)+fibonacci(i-2)])
```

because `fibonacci(i-1)` and `fibonacci(i-2)` are also lists, but it looks like you expect an integer here as a result of the addition.

Since you are using a loop in the function and have a seed list, you don't need the recursion. Just index into the list `fb`:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    fb=[0,1]
    for i in range(2,n-1):
        fb.append(fb[i-1] + fb[i-2])
    return fb

n = 9
fibonacci(n)
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

With that, your cube `map()` should work.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to replace

```
fb.append([fibonacci(i-1)+fibonacci(i-2)])
```

with

```
fb.append(fibonacci(i-1)+fibonacci(i-2))
```

Right now, you are mapping a function that takes a scalar as input onto a list containing both numbers like 0 and 1 as well as lists, like [1], for example.